# How to test an exception scenario with Hamcrest

Tags: java, testing, hamcrest

I have a method named execute() which does something and returns a boolean. Under normal situations, it returns true, but if there is an exception, (say, DataAccessException) it will capture the exception and return false.

I am trying to figure out how to test the scenario in which an exception is raised and "false" is returned, using Hamcrest.

So, here it is:

```
public boolean execute() {
    try {     ....... return true;}
    catch (DataAccessException de) { ....... return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are suppressing the `DataAccessException` inside `execute`() method, you will not be able test the exception, rather you can `assert` the result of the method call as shown below:

```
@Test
public void testExecute() {
   //Mock the code to throw DataAccessException
    Mokito.doThrow(new DataAccessException()).when(mockObj).methodName(someMethod);

    //now call execute method
    boolean actual = obj.execute();
    assertThat(actual, false);
}
```

Comment: Inside the catch clause, I am passing the exception to Log.debug before returning false.

Comment: Can i use Mockito to throw new DataAccessException and assert false, by the way?